# How to properly organize grammar with complex sentence with dashes?

Tags: conjunctions, dashes

Alright, Im writing an APLAC paper and don't know if my word choice and more importantly grammar in the following is correct:

> I left my residence, embraced teary-eyed peers and entrusted my possessions to Home Depot - this is the customary performance - and set out four weeks ago to construe a brand of the American high school unfamiliar to me.

Not sure if my use of a conjunction in the first part is accurate, and can construe be used there? Would appreciate the help.

Comment: *Construe* means to interpret, usually words. Is that what you want?

Comment: I more meant to understand

Comment: Interpret to an extent, yes, but can it be used like that

Comment: IMO, the conjunction would sound better as "as is customary," and, to be blunt, no native (American; can't speak for the English) speaker would use *construe* in that way. And TBH, I'm not sure what you're trying to say in the rest of it either. Why and how would you entrust your possessions to a hardware store? "A brand of" a school, while I could see the phrase being used in certain contexts by a certain type of author, doesn't sound particularly apt for your use case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tl;dr Yes, but it may be jarringly unusual.

*Construe* means to interpret, i.e., to determine meaning from some source of communication, usually verbal.  For example, from [*Reason, Regulation, and Realism*](https://books.google.com/books?id=_QumVitwjcYC&pg=PA178&dq=%22construe%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjG8_ufuaTPAhUE0YMKHYY7DhQ4FBDoAQhMMAk#v=onepage&q=%22construe%22&f=false) by C. A. Hooker

> How is one to understand philosophically the old proverb “Seeing is believing”? Traditional epistemology would **construe** it along these lines:….

There is a natural usage with message-laden objects like [*utterance*](https://books.google.com/books?id=cjOUtghk_MsC&pg=PA8&dq=%22construe%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiJlM_0uKTPAhXIRSYKHVrRChk4ChDoAQgyMAU#v=onepage&q=%22construe%22&f=false), *[statute](https://books.google.com/books?id=cgENAQAAMAAJ&q=%22construe%22&dq=%22construe%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiJlM_0uKTPAhXIRSYKHVrRChk4ChDoAQgbMAA)*, *case law* ([religious](https://books.google.com/books?id=HAEqAQAAMAAJ&q=%22construe%22&dq=%22construe%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiJlM_0uKTPAhXIRSYKHVrRChk4ChDoAQgfMAE) and [secular](https://books.google.com/books?id=rDyaAAAAIAAJ&q=%22construe%22&dq=%22construe%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiJlM_0uKTPAhXIRSYKHVrRChk4ChDoAQhIMAk)), an *ideology* like [feminism](https://books.google.com/books?id=Y41chR_oYGcC&pg=PA16&dq=%22construe%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiJlM_0uKTPAhXIRSYKHVrRChk4ChDoAQgsMAQ#v=onepage&q=%22construe%22&f=false), and so on.

You wish to construe an institution -- American high school (God help you) -- and this strikes me as a bit odd because I would expect you to try to construe the rules, standards, philosophy, social standards, etc. that you will encounter in your hellish journey through this particular institution. Your question is basically can you use the word *construe* with an environment metaphorically standing for all the various messages you will encounter in your interactions within this environment.

It's unusual, but not unprecedented.  Consider the following monograph: [*How the inhabitants of South African townships **construe** their spatial **environment***](https://books.google.com/books?id=Jm9PAAAAMAAJ&q=%22construe%22&dq=%22construe%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiOp-HSuKTPAhWGSiYKHUbJDA0Q6AEIHjAA).

(**emaphasis** mine)

Answer (score 1):

Actually, sky, your sentence makes no sense to me. Who are your peers? What's going to Home Depot? Is that humor? *Construe* doesn't work; *performance* doesn't either. Although em-dashes can be used there, you're better off with two separate sentences. And in a complex sentence, I would highly recommend the Oxford comma.

**Four weeks ago, I set out to discover a brand of the American high school experience unfamiliar to me: public school. I left my residence, said goodbye to my teary-eyed friends four years of boarding school strong, and entrusted my possessions to what we called Home Depot--it was customary, after all.**